# facebook iframe application authorization using developer toolkit 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, facebook

i want to make facebook iframe application using asp.net c#.

how can i make authorization using the developer toolkit 2.0
?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must have a login button in the markup...

```
<fb:login-button v="2" size="medium" onlogin="window.location.reload(true);">Connect</fb:login-button>
```

...and something like this in the `Page_Load` event of your callback page:

```
ConnectSession session = new ConnectSession(API_KEY, API_SECRET);
Api api = new Api(session);

if (session.IsConnected())
{
    // User is authenticated
}
```

Comment: sorry the version is 2.1
and there is no such methods.